# ～め ending, apparently not imperative?

Tags: verbs, syntax

Context is the song 「その血の記憶」：

> 空白のラストページに…　　 　　　　*Into [dative of motion towards] a blank LAST PAGE,*
>
> そのこぶしを叩き込めーッ！　　　　 *[Star Platinum] will throw that fist (???)*
>
> End of THE WORLD！その血の記憶！ *End of THE WORLD! That blood's memory!*
>
> (オラオラオラオラオラオラオラオラ／無駄無駄無駄無駄無駄無駄無駄無駄{むだむだむだむだむだむだむだむだ})

Point of confusion is 叩き込め. It definitely derives from 叩{たた}き込{こ}む. The conjugation is the problem.

- It ends in an `e`-series mora so it should be either imperative or participial.
- `me` is not a valid contraction for any `*ite`, so it can't be participial.
- Therefore it's imperative, "Throw that fist into a blank LAST PAGE!"

Although this makes syntactic sense it seems wrong, as if this were an imperative it would be the only imperative in the entire song which would be a massive shift in structure. What is the syntax here?

(For the record, the JoJo wiki translates this into english with a future indicative.)

Answer (score 4):

This 叩き込め is nothing but an imperative (i.e., "Crusaders, throw your fist!"). Although 叩き込め is the only imperative verb in the [entire lyrics](http://www.kasi-time.com/item-74528.html), it's used four times, so you can think it's the main "message" of the song.